# Sturdiness of an applet in Java Card

Tags: java, exception, applet, javacard

I developed an applet in Java Card and it works fine.
Now I am working on the sturdiness of this applet and more precisely, what happens if the card is deplugged during the applet execution for example.

I am wondering if there is an Exception which handle this kind of things ?

I am searching for something like :

```
try {
...
}
// If the card is disconnected while the applet execution
catch (Exception e) {
...
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the smart cards haven't any battery inside, you can't have any `try ... catch ...` like this. Alternatively you can take advantages of `Transactions`. The Transaction APIs are provided just for your goal. The operations that are between `beginTransation()` and `commitTransation()` methods, apply only if the `commitTransation()` complete successfully. And if any exeption/card tear or card reset happens before `commitTransation()`, everything returns to its original state (i.e. to the state that it has before `beginTransaction()`)

It is like this :

```
    .
    .
    JCSystem.beginTransaction();
    //put your critical code here.
    JCSystem.commitTransaction();
    .
    .
```

You can also use `JCSystem.commitTransaction();` to terminate a transaction in a specific situation as follow :

```
    .
    .
    JCSystem.beginTransaction();

    //put your critical code here.
    if (condition) {
    JCSystem.commitTransaction();
    }

    JCSystem.commitTransaction();
    .
    .
```

Note that:

1. Transactions have a limited buffer in cards. So you can't put whole the program inside a transaction. But for typical critical methods, it has enough buffer size.
2. You can't use nested Transactions.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer :)

Comment: @Abraham, nice explanation. I would like to add one more point here that :
As local variables or transient array element do not participate in a transaction so assigning the object to local variable or a transient array element should be consider carefully in order to avoid generating dangling pointers. Always use Transactions when dealing with critical things in which the partial updates can't be tolerated.